# Deep understanding: What is the underlying logic behind the way array indexes work?

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexing, string-length

**My motivation for this question**

For me the thrill of programming is when a deep understanding of the logic behind a given language enables you to "just figure things out" using that logic. So when I stumble upon something that appears to miss this kind logic it bothers me.

**How indexes work**

This is what I have learned about working with array indexes:

```
var fruit = ["Apple", "Orange", "Kiwi"]

fruit.length = 3 // returns the length of the fruit array

var rotten = fruit[2] //assigns the value "Kiwi" to the variable "rotten"

fruit[2] = "Melon" //changes the 3rd object in the array fruit from "Kiwi" to "Melon"
fruit[fruit.length] = "Melon" //adds a new object to the array fruit after "Kiwi"
```

**What bothers me about the logic**

So I have just used `.length`to obtain the information that my fruit array has a length of three. Next I want to access the third object using `var rotten = fruit[]`. My logic tells me I should do this using `var rotten = fruit[3]`. But that returns undefined because the objects are indexed 0, 1, 2.

Likewise my immediate thought would be to use the following code to add an object to an array: `fruit[fruit.length + 1] = "Melon"` because I know that the `.length` method returns "the number of the last object" in the array. This is of course not actually the case because this in reality is 2 when considering the index is 0, 1, 2.

**My question**

Is there a deeper logic behind not indexing an array using 1, 2, 3 in stead of 0, 1, 2 and thereby making it - in my opinion - more intuitive to understand and use Javascript or is this just something you should learn my heart and accept without looking for any deeper reasoning?

Comment: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/110804/why-are-zero-based-arrays-the-norm

Comment: Thank you all. I was not aiming at triggering a debate - just thought that there might actually be an underlying logic. It seems to follow from the answers that there are not even though you might to some extent can present arguments for both kinds of indexes - and that is a debate for another time and place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Fortran family languages, arrays are indexed starting at 1, as you suggest, since this is standard mathematical practice.  In the Algol-60/PASCAL family of languages, the programmer chooses the starting index — it can be 0, 1, or anything else.  In the BCPL and C family of languages, and in most modern languages (with the notable exclusion of Julia), array indices start at 0.

Over the years, it has been found out that it is convenient to have a single convention — PASCAL-style indexing is confusing when code written by different programmers is combined, it is better to choose one starting index and stick to it.

The actual choice between 0 and 1 is fairly arbitrary, but a number of [wise people](https://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/EWD/transcriptions/EWD08xx/EWD831.html) agree that starting at 0 makes a number of operations a little simpler and less error-prone.  Compare for example the following two implementations of array interleaving, 0-based:

```
if(i % 2 == 0)
    a[i / 2] = 42;
else
    b[(i - 1) / 2] = 42;
```

and 1-based:

```
if(i % 2 == 1)
    a[(i + 1) / 2] = 42;
else
    b[i / 2] = 42;
```

Comment: Umm, your example seems to be exactly the same - you use the same number of expressions and constants. I'd even argue that people intuitively handle `+` better than `-`. Dijkstra's note that `1 <= i < N + 1` is "uglier" than `0 <= i < N` is a strawman - most people using pascal used `1 <= i <= N`, which is IMO nicer than either - just a simple `[1..N]`, perfectly reasonable for PASCAL which worked with concepts like sets.

Comment: Sure.  As I said, the important point is to pick one convention and have everyone stick to it — and the industry appears to have standardised on the 0-based convention, so I advise following suit.  I personally find the 1-based convention confusing, but perhaps that's just because I've gotten used to the 0-based convention.

Comment: In the C-like world, yes. C kept close to the hardware of the time - that's how we got 0-based indices (`pointer + size * i` is a simple offset, most CPUs had instructions to do that exact thing, while `pointer + size * (i-1)` needed an extra step; of course, the compiler could change 1-based to 0-based, but C compilers were incredibly simple; funnily enough, the older PASCAL compilers, while being single-pass, didn't have a problem with that) and null-terminated strings (they had direct hardware support on some CPUs), among other things. Other languages have different conventions.